# How to center textfield (Codename one)?

Tags: java, textfield, codenameone

I'm trying to set the text alignment in a textfield in Codename One. 
I've already created a style to set the alignment but it doesn't work.

I can set the alignment to the right and left but not in center.
I would like to know how to center the text(value)  in the textfield.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that you even need to touch the Style but simply use the `setAlignment` method:

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea() ;
ta.setAlignment(TextArea.CENTER);
```

Comment: I would suggest using `ta.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.CENTER)` notice that `ta.setAlignment` is deprecated. However, if the field is editable it will probably not maintain its center alignment during editing.

Comment: Is there a way it can be done to remain at the center even during editing

Answer (score 1):

check it , it will solve your problem

```
Form   form = new Form(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
TextField textField = new TextField();
form.addComponent(textField);
textField.setAlignment(TextArea.CENTER);
form.show();
```

Comment: arent you setting the TA to the mid of the parent component instead of aligning the VALUE to the center?

Comment: It was just a question, I posted something like this and was wondering if there was a difference

Comment: Hello,

thank you for you answer.
I tried your solution (code), unfortunately it didn't work.
I'm using NetBeans with the CodeName One plugin and after trying your code, I had this exception :

http://i.imgur.com/RrW4XJ9.png

Comment: @Skyblue have you updated the libraries under project properties?

BTW: If you want someone to be notified, you need to add a @ Name in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Center alignment works if you use Textarea instead of Textfield.

```
TextArea textAreaInput = new TextArea();
```

and then :

```
textAreaInput.getAllStyles().setAlignment(TextArea.CENTER);
```

But, as Shay points out, during editing the text aligns to the left.